# Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Tags: php, pdo

Fiz um code para verificar se o usuário e email já são existentes, mas quando o usuário existe ele retorna o seguinte erro:

> Fatal error: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

```
$query_check_user_name = $this->db->prepare('SELECT username, mail FROM users WHERE username= :user_name OR
mail = :user_email');
$query_check_user_name->bindValue(':user_name', $user_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_check_user_name->bindValue(':user_email', $user_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_check_user_name->execute();
$result = $query_check_user_name->fetchAll();

if (count($result) > 0) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++) {
        $this->errors[] = ($result[$i]['user_name'] == $user_name) ? MESSAGE_USERNAME_EXISTS : MESSAGE_EMAIL_ALREADY_EXISTS;
    }
} else {
}
```

Comment: Respondi na lata, mas esqueci de a pergunta clássica: "Qual linha ocorreu esse erro"?

Comment: Outra dica: Não use o `for` para iterar com `arrays`, principalmente com aquele `count($result)` sendo chamado a cada verificação de for :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente isso

```
 $query_check_user_name->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

O PHP geralmente retorna esse erro quando você tem um objeto qualquer (desde que não implemente a interface `ArrayAccess`) e tenta acessá-lo como `array`.

Exemplo

```
$objeto = new stdClass;

$objeto->nome = 'Wallace';

$objeto['nome']; // Fatal Error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```